# NuGet CLI throw error Unable to find .nupkg

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, autofac, nuget-package

I try to build a package using NuGet CLI. 
I run next command :

```
.\nuget.exe pack D:\projects\CloudStorage.Client.csproj -OutputDirectory D:\packages -Build -Symbols -Properties Configuration=Release;
```

But always get next error:

> Error NU5012: Unable to find 'Autofac.4.9.4.nupkg'. Make sure the project has been built.

But the solution is built.

I'm using the latest version of NuGet ([v5.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads))

In bin/Release folder Autofac is present or I don't understand correctly of the difference between missed '.nupkg' and present assemblies?

[image]

Also for the mentioned project, there are present `CloudStorage.Client.nuspec` file

---

This issue was detected when I updated one nuget package(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions/)  in solution that requires now SemVer 2.0.0 package... In order to build it, I upgrade Nuget to 4.3.0+ version. The result is above.

---

Project nuspec content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
       <metadata>
           <id>CloudStorage.Client</id>
           <version>$version$</version>
           <description>CloudStorage Client</description>
           <authors>MyTeam</authors>
           <tags>$branch$</tags>
       </metadata>
    </package>
```

---

**UPD**

I've created test project, where include Autofac 4.9.4 and try to build pack for it. It was successfully created. From console I see that for Autofac was copied all 3 files to bin folder `.pdb`, `.dll` and `.xml` files... while in my "problem" project only `.dll` is copied.

Comment: Hi, which nuget  manage format your project use? Packages.config or PackageReference? I can reproduce same issue(build successfully while pack failed) in packages.config format project, and that's because the nuget.exe can't find the `Autofac.4.9.4.nupkg` in path `SolutionFolder\packages\Autofac.4.9.4`. You can check if the xx.nupkg file exists in that path, if not, run a nuget restore to check if it helps:)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Hi! Yes, it is packages.config and yes, I see `Autofac.4.9.4.nupkg` in `SolutionFolder\packages\Autofac.4.9.4`. Will try to delete older versions... maybe it can somehow help

Comment: I suggest you can delete the release folder in bin, and run the nuget pack command again, then it may display some warning to help locate this issue. For me, something is wrong with the hint path in my xx.csproj file,but since the last build is successful, when I use that nuget pack command, it always built successfully with no warning though pack failed. After I delete the bin folder and run the nuget pack command to make a clean build, the warning occurs to indicate the real issue.

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT Just did it. See that packages were copied from Solution packages folder and Autofac was there with correct version. But the same error still exists... (Note: Autofac copied only .dll and not nupkg... maybe it is an issue)

Comment: @LanceLi-MSFT, this issue was detected when I update one nuget package(https://www.nuget.org/packages/Z.EntityFramework.Extensions/)  in solution that requires now SemVer 2.0.0 package... In order to build it, I need to have Nuget 4.3.0+. I update version of nuget - and result is above

Answer (score 7):

I guess that the root cause of the issue is that `your project is not in solution folder`.

The hint paths in your xx.csproj file should be an absolute path like:
 `<HintPath>C:\Users\xxx\source\repos\PackTest\packages\Autofac.4.9.4\lib\net45\Autofac.dll</HintPath>`

instead of normal relative one:

```
<HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.4.9.4\lib\net45\Autofac.dll</HintPath>
```

1. When you use command like `nuget.exe pack D:\projects\CloudStorage.Client.csproj -build`, it will call `msbuild.exe` to build the project and then use `nuget.exe` itself to create the package. [Msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild?view=vs-2019) is build engine of VS, so it recognizes the xx.csproj file well, and it get the necessary assemblies from correct path. So the build succeeds.

   But somehow `nuget.exe` can't recognize the hintpath element, and since this project is `packages.config` format, during pack process, it will always try to find the xx.nupkg files from the **packages** folder in **Solution folder**.
2. **Normally** the `project` folder and `packages` folder are in `solution` folder, so it works well. But since your project folder(in your situation its name is `projects`) is not in Solution folder, nuget.exe won't know where to find it. That's why the error message `Unable to find 'Autofac.4.9.4.nupkg'` occurs.

And that's why the build succeeds but we can't create the nuget package.

**Here are workarounds:**

1. Create a `nuget.config` in `D:\` next to the `projects` folder.

Its content should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="D:\PackagesForThisProject" />
  </config>
</configuration>
```

And then copy the `packages` folder from `Solution Folder` to `D:\` , rename it to `PackagesForThisProject`.

Then you can create the package successfully.

2. Or you can [Migrate the `packages.config` format to `PackageReference`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/nuget/migrate-packages-config-to-package-reference/).

Comment: sorry, just start trying... will let you know later if it is working

Comment: Workaround #1 don't think is suitable for me as building of packages I should move to teamcity. Second - in progress

Comment: One more thing - similar projects that are in solution - build without problem. And also it includes Autofac 4.9.4. So maybe problem in something else but it isn't displayed...

Comment: @demo Hi, have you checked if the hintpath's format are same between the CloudStorage.Client.csproj and other projects in the solution.  And migrating to packagereference can't help resolve this issue?

Comment: @demo I assume maybe the CloudStorage.Client project locates in `D:\` while other projects which build well locates in C:\...repos\SolutionFolder.

Comment: Hi! Sorry for delay. Seems like problem was in format of building versions... Latest Nuget are sciping some 0 (zeros) in versioning... That was a problem.

Comment: @demo Hi, so it's now resolved, right? You can consider adding it as answer and mark it to share the useful info !

Comment: Workaround #1 of adding the NuGet.config with a relative path to the packages directory worked for me. i.e. <add key="repositoryPath" value=".\packages" />

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, directories structure was like below

```
MySolution.sln
MyProject\MyProject.csproj
MyProject\MyProject.nuspec
MyProject\MyProject.sln
MyProject\packages.config
packages\...
```

and command was `nuget.exe pack MyProject\MyProject.csproj`

Fix: remove file `MyProject\MyProject.sln`

Note: rename to `MyProject\MyProject.sln_` doesn't help, but rename to `MyProject\MyProject._sln` works

Nuget.exe version: 5.6.0.6591

Answer (score 1):

Solution from Nikoloy Pakudin worked from me.
I had spent almost 2 days to fix this issue.

Fix: remove file `MyProject\MyProject.sln`
or rename to `MyProject\MyProject._sln` works

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the project's "packages" folder had references to previous NuGet versions. Delete all folders within the "packages" folder. Then, select "Manage NuGet References..." from your project and allow the NuGet Package Manger restore your references. Now, try and run "nuget pack...".